# SSIS - read a single header record from a flat file or an excel file prior to processing

Tags: ssis, dataflow

Is there a method by which one can read just the first record of a file, i.e., to read header information so that a decision can be made whther or not to process the remainder of the file?

I know that with the split transformation component one can write an expression that will ignore all of the rows besides the header based on a key word in the header. I would rather not go that route as that is inefficiently reading every record in the file.

Specifically, is there script component logic that I can implement to close the file
and end the dataflow after the first record has been read?

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/2285e99f-429a-4495-84bd-66c34f906bc6/) from Todd McDermid:

> Basically, you would set up a Foreach
>   Container to loop over the files in
>   your directory.  Inside the Foreach,
>   you would determine the "file type" -
>   perhaps by creating a variable with a
>   long-winded expression on it that
>   pulls apart your file name and assumes
>   the a "file type" value - then passes
>   control on to one of five Data Flows
>   via conditional connectors. 
>   (Double-click on the standard green
>   connector, change it's Evaluation
>   Operation to Expression and
>   Constraint, and set the expression to
>   be "file_type_variable =
>   ".)  Then each Data Flow
>   picks apart one "file type".